# How to fake my android - Zuk-Z1 to look like Nexus 5x/ 6p

Tags: cyanogenmod, system, nexus-6p, nexus-5x, device-name

How to fake my android - Zuk-Z1 to look like Nexus 5x/ 6p

My office has a policy only to allow email and calendar over Gmail native app on Nexus 5/ 6/ 5x/ 6P devices with latest factory Rom. I just bought Lenovo Zuk Z1, loving the grey metallic look of it. I was trying to fake my Zuk-Z1 as Nexus 6P, so when my GMAIL client makes a request to Company-Exchange Server it looks as if coming from Nexus-6p or Nexus-5x. The reason I am not trying to spoof Nexus-5 is as it does not have a fingerprint scanner. It would be great my device-administrator allows security policy to unlock my phone using fingerprint scanner. I am in so much liking this device, at time  price-value make me glad, other times, the so premium look of it makes feel happy. I downloaded Nexus 6p factory build, not able to extract the values from the img files.

I humbly request, if some can share the value below from the Nexus 5x/6p devices.

To be changed
ro.product.model
ro.product.brand
ro.product.name
ro.product.device
ro.product.manufacturer
ro.build.fingerprint
ro.build.product=Z1
ro.build.host

I have read online, not to be changed
ro.build.version.sdk

My plan is to replace these values in caynogenmod build.prop file. rebundle it and then flash it. 
Do you think this makes sense. Do you guys think this would work. 
If this work, next I really wish to spoof boxer email UA. A great email client, i would like to use. But, for now can someone please

1. update me on the above values for nexus 5x/ 6p
2. update me if i am missing on other important values.
3. update me if you think i am dumb.

Thank you all.

Comment: If you have root permissions on your device, there's no need to bother flashing anything. Just change the **build.prop** fields you already mentioned, by inputting the corresponding Nexus values.

Comment: Thank you, I agree, but i need the values mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue to Vivek. This is what I tried and worked for me.

Before attempting, **SEE NOTES**. This assumes you are rooted.

So first I went to google playstore and downloaded a [build.prop editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.apps.build.prop.editor). I focused on these attributes for my **Moto X Pure**:

```
ro.product.model=XT1575
ro.product.brand=motorola
ro.product.name=clark_retus
ro.product.device=clark
ro.product.manufacturer=motorola
ro.build.fingerprint=motorola/clark_retus/clark:6.0/MPH24.49-18/18:user/release-keys
ro.build.product=clark
ro.build.host=ilclbld87
ro.build.version.security_patch=2016-02-01
ro.build.version.release=6.0
```

and changed them to match the **Nexus 5x**:

```
ro.build.version.release=6.0.1
ro.build.version.security_patch=2016-03-01
ro.product.model=Nexus 5X
ro.product.brand=google
ro.product.name=bullhead
ro.product.device=bullhead
ro.build.host=wpiy3.hot.corp.google.com
ro.product.manufacturer=LGE
ro.build.product=bullhead
ro.build.fingerprint=google/bullhead/bullhead:6.0.1/MMB29Q/2480792:user/release-keys
```

After making the changes. I saved and then rebooted. After that I installed Gmail (didn't have it before) and it automatically sent me a "Welcome Nexus 5x User" email after installing. That made me pretty confident that I was now viewed as a Nexus 5x, by that app at least. I added the new exchange account, entering my credentials and things worked.

Fini

**Important Notes**

1. Make a backup of your phone. Specifically a NAND backup. What this
   means is to have a custom bootloader like TWRP and make a backup
   there.
2. Backup your original build.prop file and store somewhere.
   Like on your SD card or computer.
3. Make sure GooglePlay has auto-updates disabled. This might cause some issues as it tries to update your phone with new software revisions due to it thinking you are now a Nexus 5x 6.0.1 and need the latest and greatest software for each app you have installed.

Good Luck!

Comment: Point 3. Google play updates can be disabled temporarily. Not for ever AFAIK. Won't that cause a problem later?